# Stock symbol list for German Xetra stocks on Google Finance or Yahoo Finance

Tags: stocks, germany, yahoo-finance, market-data, google-finance

I would like to have a list of the stock symbols of companies listed on Germany's Xetra exchange that can be used on Google Finance or Yahoo Finance. Where can one download this list?

Comment: Not all stocks in Xetra are listed in the US, and as _Stock Symbols_ are a US invention, some may not have any.

Comment: @curious Are you talking about US stock symbols, German WKN or ISIN?